# gfortran: multiple definitions of... first defined here

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have code that includes main program and many modules in separate files that I am linking. Currently I have a makefile that creates .o files for each module (one on separate line) and then I put them all together, such as here:

```
mpif90 - modutils
mpif90 -c modvarsym
mpif90 -c s1_Phi.f90
mpif90 -c s2_Lambda.f90

mpif90 maincode.f90 modutils.o modvarsym.o  s1_Phi.o s2_Lambda.o -o maincode
```

The above compiles fine and runs OK - except tat I suspect that I suspect array bound problems in my variables. So I include -fbounds-check maincode statement such as here:

```
mpif90 maincode.f90 modutils.o modvarsym.o  s1_Phi.o s2_Lambda.o -o -fbounds-check maincode
```

That's when numerous "multiple definition" errors appear, and the code will no longer compile. I imagine that is because of -fbounds-check: rather than just enabling checking for array bounds, it probably does some additional checks. I also suspect that the error is in the way that I enter files in the make file. However I could not find the way that would work. In these files, both modvarsym and modutils is used by the main code as well as by the other two modules. The main code uses all four modules. 
There is no include statement in these files. Maincode is the only file with the program statement, the variables are declared only once in modvarsym. Overall, the code compiles and runs without -fbounds-check. However I really want to use -fbounds-check to make sure the arrays do not overrun. Would anybody be able to put me on the right track? Thank you.

Comment: First, I assume your first command is meant to have `-c`, and your first two are meant to have `.f90` (or `.f95` or similar) suffix as otherwise the compiler shouldn't do anything for them. Second, `-o -fbounds-check maincode` (in the absence of `-c`) means to put the linked output in file `-fbounds-check` and include `maincode` (if it exists) among the files linked. Since you have already linked all your routines into `maincode`, linking those same routines again PLUS maincode produces duplicates.  ...

Comment: ... Move `-fbounds-check` *before* the `-o` at least; even better, it is usual style (though not required) to put options that affect parsing and code generation before the source file(s) as well, and in your example that is `maincode.f90`. Also note that this generates bound checks only for the routines in maincode; if there are any subscripting errors in the other routines they won't be caught. When you have a bug in a compiled language the place where a problem is *detected* may not be the actual origin, and it usually best to apply debugging options to everything you can.

Comment: Thank you very much. moving -fbounds-check before -o solved the compiling problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer @dave_thompson_085 gave in his comments, it seems to solve the problem.

First, I assume your first command is meant to have `-c`, and your first two are meant to have `.f90` (or `.f95` or similar) suffix as otherwise the compiler shouldn't do anything for them. Second, `-o -fbounds-check maincode` (in the absence of `-c`) means to put the linked output in file `-fbounds-check` and include `maincode` (if it exists) among the files linked. Since you have already linked all your routines into `maincode`, linking those same routines again PLUS `maincode` produces duplicates.

Move `-fbounds-check` before the `-o` at least; even better, it is usual style (though not required) to put options that affect parsing and code generation before the source file(s) as well, and in your example that is `maincode.f90`. Also note that this generates bound checks only for the routines in maincode; if there are any subscripting errors in the other routines they won't be caught. When you have a bug in a compiled language the place where a problem is detected may not be the actual origin, and it usually best to apply debugging options to everything you can.